# The question of inequality of expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $f(x)=f(-x)\geq0$ be a nonincreasing for $x≥0$ function, and let $ξ,η$ be r.v. Prove/disprove $P(|ξ|≤ε)≥P(|η|≤ε)$ $∀ε≥0 ⇒Ef(ξ)≥Ef(η)$.

At first I thought of applying the Markov inequality. But it did not bind the mathematical expectation between them. Then I thought to write down the integral sum of Lebesgue integral for expectations and compare them with each other. But then it is not clear how distributions of $|ξ|$ and $|η|$ are linked with distributions of f(ξ) and f(η). 
I could not provide a counterexample for discrete distributions.
Help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first observe that $P(|\xi| <\epsilon)\leq P(|\eta| <\epsilon)$ is also true (by taking limits).

Now, for any $t \geq 0$ observe that $f^{-1} ([t,\infty)$ is an interval of the type $(-\infty,a)$ or an interval of the type $(-\infty,a]$. From this it follows that $P(f(|\xi|) \geq t) \geq P(f(|\eta|) \geq t)$. Integrating this w.r.t. $t$ from $0$ to $\infty$ we get $Ef(|\xi|) \geq Ef(|\eta|)$. Since $f$ is an even function this gives $Ef(\xi) \geq Ef(\eta)$.

Comment: How we can observe that $P(|ξ|<ϵ)≤P(|η|<ϵ)$ if it isn't true by condition of the task?

Comment: f is non-negative by the condition too.

Comment: @Shorty12319 Apply the given inequality with $\epsilon$ changed to $\epsilon-\frac 1  n$ and the let $n \to \infty$. We always have $P(X <a) =\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X \leq a-\frac 1 n)$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy How this heps us? I can't understand

Comment: If $P(X≤a−1/n) \leq P(Y\leq a-1/n) $ then this limits are the same

Comment: I understand your solution! In my opinion the first string is unnecessary. Thank you!